# Multiprocess using AIDL between different application

Tags: android, android-activity

I have two app: call app A and app B. which app A is library of app B.
In app A, I want to create Service to implement some method,and app B I only call method from A using AIDL.
How can I connect to my service in app A from app B using AIDL?

Comment: see http://developer.android.com/guide/components/aidl.html

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I still have not found a way to solve my problems. Can you guidelines for my case.

Comment: "Now, when a client (such as an activity) calls bindService() to connect to this service, ...", please read the whole page